# Rails 4 url_for with host constraint

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, ruby-on-rails-4, routes

We created a multi tenancy application with multiple sites and each site is able to modify the routes from a backend.

in routes.rb we load the dynamic routes for all sites and put them into a host constraint like this

**routes.rb**

```
Frontend::Application.routes.draw do

  DynamicRoutes.load

end
```

**app/models/dynamic_routes.rb**

```
class DynamicRoutes
  # dynamically loads the routes from settings into the routes.rb file
  # and adds a host constraint to just match with the current sites host
  # http://codeconnoisseur.org/ramblings/creating-dynamic-routes-at-runtime-in-rails-4
  def self.load
    if Site.table_exists?
      Frontend::Application.routes.draw do
        Site.includes(:setting).each do |site|
          site.routes.each do |route|
            # write the route with the host constraint
            constraints(:host => site.hostname) do
              case route[0]
              when :shop_show
                match "#{route[1]}", to: 'shops#show', via: [:get], as: "shop_show_#{site.id}"
              end
            end
          end
        end
      end
    end
  end

  # allows to reload the routing
  # e.g. when changes in route settings where made
  #
  def self.reload
    Rails.application.reload_routes!
  end
end
```

So we create all routes for each site and match them with a host constraint. This works fine unless we use the **url_for** helper

```
@site = Site.find_by(hostname: request.host)
url_for controller: 'shop', action: 'show', host: @site.hostname
```

url_for returns the first matching url, doesnt matter from which host it should belong to. so the host constraint is not used, even if I put a host: param

Do you have any idea, of how its possible to use url_for with host constraints?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have had the same task in my application. **url_for** ignores host param. But we could create additional path helpers in our ApplicationController in the following way:

**ApplicationController.rb**

```
%w( shop_show ).each do |helper|
  helper_name = "#{helper}_path".to_sym
  helper_method helper_name
  define_method(helper_name) { |*args| send "#{helper}_#{site.id}_path", *args }
end
```

After that you are able to use universal path **shop_show_path** in your views. Of course, you should dynamically assign **site** variable depending on your host/domain.